# Why is searching by Class Chain in iOS faster than XPath?

Tags: python, xpath, automation, appium-android, appium-ios

I am working on an Appium project to automate an app using Python in both iOS and Android. I usually stick with using XPath to search for elements but in iOS, there is a wonderful searching mechanism called `Class Chain`, which allows you to search by element's class, such as `XCUIElementTypeStaticText` for `XCUITest`.

So I was comparing the performance of searching by XPath and Class Chain, to which I found out that Class Chain performance is much faster than XPath, up to 7 times faster. A search that takes XPath 7 seconds can be done in just 1 second using Class Chain.

Example:

A simple search for a text that equals to "Hello" in `name` attribute

XPath: `//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name='Hello']` takes 8.31 seconds

Class Chain: `**/XCUIElementTypeStaticText['name == "Hello"']` takes 2.17 seconds

A video showing the speed difference [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMCE2-Q68j4)

I would like to ask why are they so different in term of performance? Or is this performance difference only limited to Python?

Comment: As a matter of interest, how big is the XML flie you are searching? Not that I can answer the question, only someone with detailed knowledge of both mechanisms can do that. But both search times seem very slow, unless you're searching gigabytes.

Comment: I have not actually inspected the size of the XML tree that Appium has generated, I can post an update with that. As a matter of fact, I asked this coz I'm interested at how they are so vastly different too.